# Ignore Postgresql batch insert errors

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, batch-insert

Assume this simple SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (val1,val2),(val3,val4),(val5,val6);
```

Lets say `val3` is invalid value for `col1`. This would cause psql to abort whole INSERT command - it would not insert `(val1,val2)` nor `(val5,val6)` either.

Is it possible to make postgresql ignore this error so it does not insert `(val3,val4)` pair but would still proceed with `(val1,val2)` and `(val5,val6)`?

I'm getting daily database dumps in text files from my partner (can't change that), which I use to make my copy of it. Sometimes his huge INSERT queries cause errors like:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

... which makes whole 30000+ values not inserted to the table, because one of those values is wrong.

Comment: Btw. One solution I came up with is parsing that text file and changing all batch INSERT commands to multiple single-value commands. But before I implement that - maybe you guys came up with better solution.

Comment: You'd probably be way better off using the COPY statement instead of a big insert.

Comment: Also, how are these files prepared?  **Why** are there illegal byte sequences in there?

Comment: @Pointy: I have no idea why. Those are prepared by other company from their database (MySQL I guess). I can't force them to change the dump format.

Comment: Well what'd probably be best then would be to write some simple filter to transform the "INSERT" syntax into a CSV file, and also to filter out bogus UTF-8 sequences.  Then you can use COPY FROM, which would be a lot faster than a bunch of INSERT statements anyway.

Comment: Right. That would be even better than translating it to many single-row inserts. I'll do that if nobody comes up with better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The application that processes the input file needs to wrap each INSERT statement with a savepoint. If the insert fails, it can be rolled back to the last savepoint. Something like:

(pseudo code)

```
foreach line
  set savepoint
  try 
    insert current line
  catch 
    rollback to savepoint
  end
endloop
commit
```